# how to test/use zend in wamp 2.2?

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

I am using win 7 system, I have installed wamp 2.2, I open `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1`, I can see some zend info, eg: Zend Extension 220090626... so does this mean zend is already installed in wamp 2.2?
I did a test:

```
<?php
$date=new Zend_Date();
echo $date; 
?>
```

But it shows:

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Date' not found in `D:\wamp\www\test.php` on line 2

So how could I know if the zend is installed already? and how could I test/use it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS

1.YOU CONFIG ZEND LIBRARY FILE

2.DOWNLOAD ZEND LIBRARY FILE  and paste this location C:\wamp\bin

3.some changes need in wamp server following steps given

you do it following steps

1.copy the zendframework file into the => C:\wamp\bin

2.add bin path to environmental variables

path => "C:\wamp\bin\zendframework\bin"

3.change the php.ini file in wamp server like that below:

; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\zendframework\library"

4.change the httpd.conf in apache like that below:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

which means remove the #.

5.restart the wamp server.